# Getting xpath of an elements based on the content on one

Tags: html, xpath, automation

I want to get the xpath of td[6] after matching the content in the cell td[3] according to my conditions.
Please help,
 Xpath I want is ,
  **if td[3]/span contains text "CITE_COS" then
    go to td[6]/span of same row**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Corresponding XPath would be :

```
//tr/td[6][preceding-sibling::td[3][contains(.,"CITE_COS")]]
```

Look for the 6th td inside a tr element where the third td element contains "CITE_COS".

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it using for loops.